# Create and display a ListView of the ZXing ProductDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor, adapter

I created an app for scanning barcodes and QR code using the ZXing library. I also implemented a `database` that stores the scanned products. I need to implement a `listview` to display the stored products. any ideas?

here are classes:

BarCodeActivity

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.spot_pay);
      Button addButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.addMenuButton);
      addButton.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener(){
          public void onClick (View v){
              startActivity(new Intent(CodiceBarreActivity.this, AggiungiCodiceActivity.class));
          }
          });
  }   
static final class ProductData {
    String barcode;
    String format;
    String title;
    BigDecimal price;
  }
}
```

ProductDatabase:

```
 private SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static class ProductDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public ProductDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

            sql.append("create table ").append(PRODUCT_TABLE)
                .append("(  ")
                .append("   _id integer primary key,")
                .append("   barcode text,")
                .append("   format text,")
                .append("   title text,")
                .append("   price currency")
                .append(")  ");

            db.execSQL(sql.toString());    

            Log.d(TAG, PRODUCT_TABLE + "table created");

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
              db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + PRODUCT_TABLE);       
              Log.d(TAG, PRODUCT_TABLE + "table dropped");
                onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public CodiciDatabase(Context context) {
        ProductDatabaseHelper helper = new ProductDatabaseHelper(context);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public boolean insert(ProductData product) {
        ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();
        vals.put("barcode", product.barcode);
        vals.put("format", product.format);
        vals.put("title", product.title);
        vals.put("price", product.price.multiply(ONE_HUNDRED).longValue());

        return db.insert(PRODUCT_TABLE, null, vals) != -1;
    }
       }
```

AddProduct

```
    private static final int REQUEST_BARCODE = 0;
    private static final ProductData mProductData = new ProductData();





    private EditText mBarcodeEdit;
    private EditText mFormatEdit;
    private EditText mTitleEdit;
    private EditText mPriceEdit;
    private Button mScanButton;
    private Button mAddButton;
    private CodiciDatabase mProductDb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

        mBarcodeEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.barcodeEdit);
        mFormatEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeFormatEdit);
        mTitleEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleEdit);
        mPriceEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.priceEdit);
        mScanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanButton);
        mScanButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mAddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        mAddButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mProductDb = new CodiciDatabase(this); // not yet shown
    }




    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.scanButton:
            Intent intent = new Intent ("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_BARCODE);
            break;

        case R.id.addButton:
            String barcode = mBarcodeEdit.getText().toString();
            String format = mFormatEdit.getText().toString();
            String title = mTitleEdit.getText().toString();
            String price = mPriceEdit.getText().toString();

            String errors = validateFields(barcode, format, title, price);
            if (errors.length() > 0) {
                showInfoDialog(this, "Please fix errors", errors);
            } else {
                mProductData.barcode = barcode;
                mProductData.format = format;
                mProductData.title = title;
                mProductData.price = new BigDecimal(price);

                mProductDb.insert(mProductData);
                showInfoDialog(this, "Success", "Product saved successfully");
                resetForm();
            }
            break;
        }   
    }

        }


    private void resetForm() {
        mBarcodeEdit.getText().clear();
        mFormatEdit.getText().clear();
        mTitleEdit.getText().clear();
        mPriceEdit.getText().clear();

    }


    private void showInfoDialog(Context context, String title, String information) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder (context)
        .setMessage(information)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        }).show();  
    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_BARCODE){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String barcode = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                mBarcodeEdit.setText(barcode);

                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                mFormatEdit.setText(format);
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                finish();
            }

        }
    }
}

    private static String validateFields(String barcode, String format, 
            String title, String price) {
            StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();

            if (barcode.matches("^\\s*$")) {
                errors.append("Barcode required\n");
            }

            if (format.matches("^\\s*$")) {
                errors.append("Format required\n");
            }

            if (title.matches("^\\s*$")) {
                errors.append("Title required\n");
            }

            if (!price.matches("^-?\\d+(.\\d+)?$")) {
                errors.append("Need numeric price\n");
            }

            return errors.toString();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overview of what you need to do:

Run a query on your database that will return a [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) to you. Once you've got that you'll have to make make a [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) and override its getView() method to inflate and populate the row Views. After that you can use the ListView.setAdapter() method passing in an instance of your adapter. It will handle updating the list on the screen for you whenever there is new data.

I suggest instead of trying to tackle this in your own project you take a break from that and go do this [Notepad tutorial from the developer docs.](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) It is very small and simple but once you are complete you will have some sample code to use when you are working on doing this for your barcode application.